# Display devise minimum password length error on sign in page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise's validatable module and in `devise.rb` have written **config.password_length = 10..128** but it does not validate the password length on sign in. Need to stop the user to login if password is not between the password length specified.

Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This option doesn't affect sign in. It validates that the password for a user should be between 8 and 128 characters long when the record is saved.

**UPDATE**

If you want to stop someone signing in, you need to override `active_for_authentication?`

```
class User
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && password_is_long_enough?
  end

  def password_is_long_enough?
    # logic to check password is long enough
  end
end
```

However, because the password is hashed, you will not know how long is it so I'm not sure this help you :(

Comment: @jordelver..But, if I need to stop the user to login then what should be done.

Comment: Why would you want to stop the user logging in if their password isn't the right size? It wouldn't make sense to do that, would it?

Comment: @jordelver..Thanks,,but actually there are some accounts in my application having password length less than 10 but current limit is 10, so now do not want those accounts to login or use the application means need a way to stop those users to login and just showing them the error message on sign in page during sign in process.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I'm not sure it helps you :(

Comment: Actually, the password is hashed in the database (`encrypted_password` attribute), but the password they entered on the login form (`password` attribute) isn't.  It is hashed to compare against the `encrypted_password` in the database of course, but the `password` attribute itself should remain the plain text password which you can check for length.